# Создание платной подписки в приложении в Google Play

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток!

Не совсем ясен механизм создания платной подписки в приложении. Подписка это как контент для продажи в приложении ? 
В хелпе гугла https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=ru
пятым пунктом создания подписки:
Укажите идентификатор контента для продажи. Где его взять ?
Есть какой-либо подробный мануал с примером как сделать подписку в приложении ?

Comment: возможный [пример настройки платежей](http://savepearlharbor.com/?p=165065), обратите внимание на `static final String SKU_DONATE_1 = "donate_1_usd";`

Comment: Насколько я понял в основной части статьи описано как сделать донат через покупку в приложении ?

Comment: исходя из статьи да, но там указано как Вам сделать идентификатор.

Comment: Статья хороша, спасибо. Но в консоле убрали тип "неограниченный контент" к сожалению, мне бы очень подошел данный способ через пожертвования